# Yosemite installer made my account into a guest account

Tags: macos, user-account, guest-account

While upgrading to OSX Yosemite, I quickly skipped forward in the different menus, and must have inevertenly created a new account.

Now my old proper account has become a guest account, with parental restrictions and what not. I cannot edit the account in the System Preferences, the user is greyed out even though I've unlocked it.

[image]

I've tried to log out from the "guest" account, but...
[image]

No I don't want to delete my home folder, thank you very much.

What to do?

Comment: For quest account it is "normal" to delete all files on log out.

Comment: It is not possible to "inadvertently create a new account" with admin privileges, and inadvertently set the guest account to parenteral restrictions. So, lets assume you wanted to create a new accounts, but now you want the files from the guest account in to your new admin account? is that the question?

Comment: This is the last resort. I could do a `sudo cp -r ~guest/* ~newUser` to copy all files from the guest users home directory, then log out the guest account and delete that user. How is this going to affect my TimeCapsule backups? The last backup I have (on usb hdd) is about a week old.